# What are the types of the phoneme distribution? How to define them?

Tags: phonetics, phonology

I was given a task to define the types of the phoneme distribution in these words:

> tea [tiː] – stay [steɪ] – try [traɪ] – twice [twaɪs] – little [ˈlɪtl]

But I have no idea how to do that. Could you give me a hint or advice?

Maybe it's about **complementary** and **contrastive** distribution and **free-variants** (that's what I've found in the internet). But I don't understand all that abstruse terms. Perhaps people who are familiar with this subject, can explain it in simple words?

Comment: Do you not have a book or syllabus you are working from? That would seem the logical place to start.

Comment: Yes, I have. But there is nothing about phoneme distribution in it. Probably I'm supposed look for this information myself.

Comment: Recommended reading: http://ebooks.unibuc.ro/filologie/mateescu/pdf/52.pdf

Comment: You should ask whoever gave you that task.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like the exercise may be about the vowel sounds. English vowels can generally be divided into two categories. One category of vowels, called "**lax vowels**", have restricted distribution in stressed syllables: they can only occur before a consonant, and not before another vowel or at the end of a word. In contrast, the "**tense vowels**" can occur without any following consonant. The vowel phonemes [iː] [eɪ] and [aɪ] are tense, and [ɪ] is lax. (Sometimes, the distinction is given in terms of syllabification: it is said that lax vowels can only occur in **closed syllables** (syllables that end in a consonant sound), while vowels of either type can occur in **open syllables** (syllables that end in the vowel sound).